# How can plain HTML controls be referenced from ASP.Net controls?

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

Here's my scenario, for which I guess there's a simple solution I'm missing: I want to add a confirm button for each delete link in a MVC app, so when I try this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { id = "_delete_" })%>
<asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="_delete_" ConfirmText="Want it or not?" />
```

I get this:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The TargetControlID of 'ConfirmButtonExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID '_delete_' could not be found.
```

Problem is that the asp:ConfirmButtonExtender control is parsed before render happens, therefore no "*delete*" HTML control is present - yet.

How can I get this right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a JavaScript confirm to the HTML attributes collection.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },  new { onclick = "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');", id = "_delete_" })%>
```

Comment: Good answer, ++. Still, what I wonder is whether there's a way to refer to HTML controls from ASP ones.

Comment: Well you can always reference the form from ASP.NET server side code. That is all Web Controls are, just wrapped in all of the Microsoft stuff. Like Request.Form["htmlFormElement"]

Comment: Did this help or answer what you are looking for, or am I off target?